# Extended Display behaving strangely after installing Windows 10 update 1809

Tags: windows-10, extended-desktop

I have two monitors as extended display on a Windows 10 pro. At random time, suddenly one Monitor - Monitor A ( but could be either one) - became like a black hole. Below are specific behaviors.

I can move the mouse to that monitor. I can see the mouse pointer moving on that monitor. But there is no response if I right-click the mouse.

On that monitor A, if I click on a task bar item, the item program opens on the other monitor B, or there is no response at all (because that item program is supposed to open up on monitor A).

On monitor B, if I move a window to monitor A, the window disappears like I moved it outside the extended display.

The problem usually occurs after the machine is back on from a hibernation. It resolves itself after I log off and then log back in.

Any advise on this? Thanks.

Comment: Reinstall the graphics drivers?

Comment: Boot into Safe mode, uninstall the video card driver, shutdown using a gentle press on the power button, reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So far the issue has not occurred again.